# Unity Mobile Controll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I tried adapting my game to be able to play it on mobile devices, started by watching youtube tutorials due to me being very not experienced in unity and everything i found was old or not what i wanted also i found old assets from unity named "Standart Assets for unity 2018" and it had what i  wanted to achive but it seems the package is decomisioned. So is there any way of controlling a character by ui buttons or by some sort of joysticks. I mean moving around and being able to look around aka rotate camera?

As i mentioned before i tried looking for tutorials and asking chat gpt but all the the solution si found was outdated. So i think something like if button clicked:  transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); I even made a prettey working code but it didnt work as intendet and i needed to click it every time to move and of course i want it to be able to press the button and walk.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the Standard Assets package is completely deprecated, there are a couple of newer packages that probably are of interest to you, specifically:

- Starter Assets - First Person Character Controller (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-first-person-character-controller-urp-196525)
- Starter Assets - Third Person Character Controller (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-third-person-character-controller-urp-196526)

These packages come with fully-functional multi-platform inputs (with keyboard controls and fully functional touchscreen controls), using the [New Input System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.6/manual/index.html).

Yes, you will need to refactor a decent amount of your existing codebase to accept inputs from the New Input System (it works considerably differently to the old Input System), but I'd suggest making a copy of the `FirstPersonController.cs`/`ThirdPersonController.cs` class and then using that as a template to rewrite your existing code in a way that will work with the New Input System.